# No content in table scroll-bar should come

Tags: scrollbar, tableview, javafx-8

When I am having data in the tableview (which is custom component), then horizontal scrollbar is visible, but if there will no data and only columns are there then scroll-bar is not visible.

Is it because of custom component I made or my FXML needs some changes.

FXML

```
<AnchorPane stylesheets="prj.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" >
         <children>
            <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                <content>
                    <prjTableView minWidth="500.0" maxWidth="500.0" prefWidth="500.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" fx:id="treeTableView" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                        <styleClass>
                            <String fx:value="k-table-view" />
                            <String fx:value="redBorder" />
                        </styleClass>
                    </prjTreeTableView>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <HBox alignment="BASELINE_LEFT">
                <children>
                    <HBox>
                        <children>
                            <Label text="Page Size">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="2.0" top="5.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </Label>
                            <TextField fx:id="itemsPerPage" maxWidth="-Infinity"
                                minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="40.0" text="50">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets left="8.0" top="6.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                                <tooltip>
                                    <Tooltip text="Enter desired page number" />
                                </tooltip>
                            </TextField>
                            <Pagination fx:id="pagination" maxWidth="-Infinity"
                                minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="235.0"
                                translateX="1.0" translateY="1.0">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </Pagination>
                            <Label fx:id="displayInfo">
                                <HBox.margin>
                                    <Insets top="5.0" />
                                </HBox.margin>
                            </Label>
                        </children>
                    </HBox>
                </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: add this 2 in scrollpane tag hbarPolicy="ALWAYS"  vbarPolicy="ALWAYS"

Comment: If I remove fitToWidth="true" then it is showing the scrollbar but it is not fitting the entire width. right hand side area is empty and table it limited to certain width. It is not taking the entire width off the window.